# Is there an alternative to the manifest file when using routes in SAPUI5 >= 1.30?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

As of SAPUI5 1.30, the configuration of the routes and targets its configured in the manifest.json file. That seems just fine for small apps (with, for example, 5 views and 5 controllers). However, lets say that I have a larger app, with dozens of views and controllers - in this scenario, the manifest.json file will grow immensely to hold all the routes and targets of the application, and it does not seem as a good practice to me. Is there any other way to configure the routes in a more "scalable" way, when dealing with really huge apps with many views and controllers?

Comment: Hi André, i think this has not been foreseen on e purpose because SAP don't target the type of apps (huge) that you describe. Have you seen the [Fiori Design Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design/)?

Comment: Where is the difference between a fat Component.js holding the routes or a fat manifest.json holding them? In general it is wise to split your app into several components if grows huge.